# NullpointerExceptionが発生する原因

Tags: java

2つのプログラムでカートの中身を表示するプログラムを作成しました。
Cart.java 
Item.java
しかし実行するとNullpointerExceptionとなってしまいます。改善策をご教授願いたいです。
配列の代入が自信ないです。
Cart.java

```
public class Cart {
    Item[] items;
    int num=0,i;
    void addItem(Item x){
        items[num]=x;
        num++;  
    }
    void info(){
        for(i=0;i<=num;i++){
            items[num].toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Item.getNumberOfInstances());
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        Item i1 = new Item("PC", 98000);
        Item i2 = new Item("Display", 40000);
        cart.addItem(i1);
        cart.addItem(i2);
        cart.info();
        System.out.println(Item.getNumberOfInstances());
    }
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    int price,i=0;
    Item(String a,int b){
        this.name=a;
        this.price=b;
        i++;
    }
    int getNumberOfInstances(){
        return i;
    }
    public String toString(Item c){
        return c.name+","+c.price;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getNumberOfInstances()` はインスタンスメソッドなのでそもそも `Item.getNumberOfInstances()` ではコンパイルが通らないのでは?

Comment: 配列にはあらかじめ確保したサイズ以上にあとから値を追加することができませんので、`ArrayList`などを使用するようにします。

Answer (score 1):

（既にコメントで指摘されている点は実行ができていることから投稿時のミスであるとして、）

**NullpointerException** が起きる原因は配列の割り当てをしていないためです。

通常配列は
`データ型[] 配列の名前 = new データ型[配列のサイズ];`
のようにして使用します。

投稿されたサンプルの場合右側部分がないので、null初期化されてそれを使用しようとするので例外が起きます。

なので、
`Item[] items = new Item[100];`
のようにするか
コンストラクタで
`items = new int[100];`
のようにしてやります。

あと、
配列はサイズの拡張ができませんので、配列を使用する場合はその範囲に気を付ける必要があります。
例えば先の例のようにサイズを１００で確保した場合`num`が１００になったらそれ以上追加することはできません。

また、

```
for(i=0;i<=num;i++){
    items[num].toString();
}
```

は

```
for(i=0;i<num;i++){
    items[i].toString();
}
```

の間違い(`num`は次の代入位置であるため)です。

Comment: ありがとうございました。おかげさまでエラーを取り除くことができました！！

Comment: @ゆゆふわ この回答で問題が解決したのであればこの回答を[承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) 下さい。